# putExtra(), getStringExtra() - why it does not work?

Tags: java, android

I suspect there is only some stupid mistake, but I'm stuck. The problem is simple: my String `path` is not send to `MainActivity`.

1. Creating intent in FileListActivity.class

   ```
   intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       intent.putExtra("path", fileName);
       Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " set to play!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Receiving intent in MainActivity.class

   ```
   protected void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   Toast.makeText(this, "path set" + getIntent().getStringExtra("path"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   if(getIntent().hasExtra("path")) try {
       mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("path")));
       mediaPlayer.prepare();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   }

Toast in `FileListActivity` shows right filename. In `MainActivity` it is null.

Comment: try `getIntent().getExtra().getString("path")` - I had a similar problem and that worked for me.

Comment: Nothing unfortunately. What is more interesting elsewhere similar code works o.O

Comment: I regularly have errors with getStringExtra or getIntExtra, and using the change I suggested always solved it for me :/

Comment: Anyway thank you very much for your interest!

Comment: I'm a bit confused why are you using the flags when opening the MainActivity? I'm suspecting that MainActivity has called FileListActivity in the first place? If so - from the MainActivity call FileListACtivity with `startActivityForResult` - it's a better implementation for your need.

Comment: @Malvinka : In your `FileListActivity` is `filename` actually defined as a `String`?

Comment: Sean, after the first call of FileListActivity activities of this class are called a few times again. And, at the end, I need to close them all with one click. I had a problem with it and this is the only solution I found. You can find a bit more about it here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575036/finishactivity-closing-all-activities-with-exact-request-code

Comment: @Malvinka : Did you see my comment above? Is `filename` actually a `String` or is it something else (such as a `Url`)?

Comment: @Sqounk - I missed it, sorry! filename is a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding `protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent)` in `MainActivity` as follows...

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Relaunching `MainActivity` using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and calling `getIntent()` in the `MainActivity` `onResume()` method won't get the new `Intent` and it simply gets the original `Intent` which won't have your `path` extra.

By overriding `onNewIntent(...)` and using it to call `setIntent(...)`, the new `Intent` overwrites the original one and the call to `getIntent()` in `onResume()` should get the correct data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still I have a problem unfortunately. After adding this piece of code my app crushed. After sending intent from FileListActivity app just stops with the msg "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped". It looks like it doesnt even reach MainActivity again.

Comment: @Malvinka : In that case, edit your original question and post the logcat showing the stacktrace of any exceptions which are being thrown.

Comment: I found the problem. It is no longer connected to the original question. It looks like ur solution works. Thanks again for your interests, answers and patience!

Answer (score 1):

getStringExtra() returns null if the value passed to putExtra() was not a String object.

Judging by the comments to the question, this is not the answer in this specific case. However, it is worth mentioning because this is a very common cause for the problem "putExtra(), getStringExtra() - why it does not work?"

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way in MainActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle pathBundle=getIntent().getExtras();

     if(pathBundle!=null)
      {
        String myPath=pathBundle.getString("path");
      }
 }
```

And In onResume method

```
  protected void onResume()
{
 super.onResume();
   try 
{
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(myPath)); // Dont forget to declare myPath String globally.
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem..

Comment: if(pathBundle!=null) this checks whether bundle receiving any extra stuff or not ie it will check for null or empty. Secondly, If bundle is not null then get the extra which i have saved in string variable myPath.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately this onResume() method crushed  my app at the start already. I have no idea why, I just copy-paste it o.O

Comment: App starts, a white screen shows up (without layout) and I have a msg "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped." I checked: it is onResume method that is a problem.

Comment: why dont you just put a log and check whether you are getting the string or value in myPath string... and make sure other things are well defined ie ids of media Player and other stuff in your code which i cant c at the moment..

Comment: @Malvinka : I think I know what the problem is but unless you read and answer my comments on your original question, I'm not going to post an answer.

Comment: A.R. thank you very much for your interest and patience. I checked: myPath in onCreate method is still doesnt set. Probably the problem is somewhere else. I will be working on it.

Comment: @Squonk - I am really really sorry! I am new here, I forgot to look at original question. I thought it is timeline or sth like this. I already answer there. And I promise not to do this again ;) Hope u will forgive me my heedlessness.

Comment: @Malvinka : No problem. See my answer - it's the only possible reason I can think of for what you're seeing and it's caused by `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`